# route packets from specific hosts to virtual device

Tags: networking, routing, multicast, ip-routing, tunnel

PIMv2 I think the issue is with multicast.

I want to create a GRE tunnel that supports multicast PIMv2. I am seeing the server sending PIMv2 Hello messages to my gre tunnel but my machine is not responding.

```
ip tunnel add [g0] mode gre remote [remote ip] local [local ip] ttl 32
ip link set [g0] multicast on
ip link set [g0] up
ip addr add [x.x.x.x/8] dev g0
```

After creating this gre tunnel, the route is shown in my route table and my ip addr show dev g0 also shows that the interface is up.

The server is still sending PIMv2 Hello messages.

Comment: be careful with the use of the word broadcast. It can have multiple specific interpretations, such as a Ethernet frame having the destination MAC address ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff or the IPv4 packet having the reserved destination address in an IP LAN so that it will be converted there as a broadcast frame instead of triggering an ARP request to resolve the destination. So what is your specific meaning of broadcast? It would help if you gave examples with values to avoid misinterpreting the question. Maybe your question is as simple as "how do I route?" but I can't know.

Comment: Now that you've completely changed the question, I'm deleting my answer.